# Reading in an XML file that doesn't has .xml as extension

Tags: android, xml, plist

I'm currently developing an app that wants to read out XML-data and show it to the user. The problem is, that my app crashes, when it should read the file. It's a plist by the way.

I'm trying to handle it like this

```
        URL sourceURL;
        sourceURL = new URL("censored.com/?plist");
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sourceURL.openStream()));
```

But the app crashes. It doesn't crash when I comment out the line where he has to read the file, so I'm pretty sure that the problem lies here.

Normally I would call the xml-file like this: censored.com/?plist.xml, but this file has no file extension. When I go to the site and type censored.com/?plist.xml or censored.com?plist.plist I get redirected to their main page.

How do I handle this file now? I thought it would be possible to save the xml-file to the assets folder and work from there, but that doesn't seem to work. I would greatly appreciate it, if you could tell me how to read in that Plist/XML-File.

I'm working with XMLWise by the way.

Comment: "But the app crashes" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. "that doesn't seem to work" -- this is not a very helpful description of your symptoms.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare - I deleted the LogCat and started the app again, but Logcat doesn't give out an error message? Did I maybe deleted something I shouldn't have deleted? Well is it maybe the URL that is wrong? I mean, maybe the URL has to be censored.com/plist.xml instead of ?format=plist?

Comment: "but Logcat doesn't give out an error message" -- then you are not crashing.